# Spresenseカーネルの再ビルドでmake buildkernel でのエラー

Tags: spresense, makefile

カーネルのコンフィグレーションを変更して再ビルドすると下記のエラーに成ります。

```
make[2]: ディレクトリ '/home/soeta/MyHome/tools/spresense/nuttx/sched' に入ります
make[2]: *** 'clock_initialize.o' に必要なターゲット '/home/soeta/MyHome/spresense/nuttx/include/nuttx/config.h' を make するルールがありません.  中止.
make[2]: ディレクトリ '/home/soeta/MyHome/tools/spresense/nuttx/sched' から出ます
LibTargets.mk:68: ターゲット 'sched/libsched.a' のレシピで失敗しました
make[1]: *** [sched/libsched.a] エラー 2
make[1]: ディレクトリ '/home/soeta/MyHome/tools/spresense/nuttx' から出ます
Makefile:131: ターゲット 'buildkernel' のレシピで失敗しました
make: *** [buildkernel] エラー 2
```

上記のディレクトリに新しく生成されたconfig.h は，存在します。

対処方法を教えて下さい。

以上よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

なぜか nuttx/sched/Make.dep のmake依存関係ファイルが壊れてしまったとかでしょうか。

```
$ make distcleankernel
```

してから再度カーネルのコンフィグレーションからやり直してみるのが良いと思います。

distcleankernelするとコンフィグレーションファイル(nuttx/.config)も削除されてしまうので、
それを避けたい場合は、

```
$ cd sdk
$ ./tools/mkdefconfig.py -k tmp
```

と、configs/kernel/tmp-defconfig に一旦コンフィグレーションファイルを保存しておいてから、

```
$ make distcleankernel
$ ./tools/config.py -k tmp
$ make buildkernel
```

とカーネルビルドをやり直してみてください

Comment: make distcleankernel にて，ビルドが通る様に成りました。